# Error: "java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map" on my MapReduce class (using Hadoop 2.2.0)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, ioexception, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to execute a MapReduce program on localhost by Hadoop.

I wrote a program to count the word in a text file.
The source code is very simple:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;


public class WordCount {

    static int printUsage() {
        System.out.println("wordcount [-m <maps>] [-r <reduces>] <input> <output>");
        ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.out);
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<String> otherArgs = new ArrayList<String>();

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        for(int i=0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            try {
                if ("-m".equals(args[i])) {
                    conf.setInt("mapreduce.job.maps", Integer.parseInt(args[++i]));
                } else if ("-r".equals(args[i])) {
                    conf.setInt("mapreduce.job.reduces", Integer.parseInt(args[++i]));
                } else {
                    otherArgs.add(args[i]);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException except) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Integer expected instead of " + args[i]);
                System.exit(printUsage());
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException except) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Required parameter missing from " +
                        args[i-1]);
                System.exit(printUsage());
            }
        }
        // Make sure there are exactly 2 parameters left.
        if (otherArgs.size() != 2) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Wrong number of parameters: " +
                    otherArgs.size() + " instead of 2.");
            System.exit(printUsage());
        }

        Path input = new Path(otherArgs.get(0));
        Path output =new Path(otherArgs.get(1));

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
            job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, input);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);

    }

    public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.cleanup(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.map(key, value, context);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.setup(context);
        }

    }

    public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.cleanup(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.reduce(key, values, context);
        }
        @Override
        public void run(Context arg0) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.setup(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I executed it by command:

`yarn jar wordcount.jar /input /output`

I received  this error:

```
14/05/10 19:10:33 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/05/10 19:10:34 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/05/10 19:10:34 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
14/05/10 19:10:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1399731445858_0009
14/05/10 19:10:37 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1399731445858_0009 to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/05/10 19:10:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://dario-R510-P510:8088/proxy/application_1399731445858_0009/
14/05/10 19:10:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1399731445858_0009
14/05/10 19:10:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1399731445858_0009 running in uber mode : false
14/05/10 19:10:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/05/10 19:11:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1399731445858_0009_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1050)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.map(WordCount.java:92)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.map(WordCount.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.run(WordCount.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

14/05/10 19:11:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1399731445858_0009_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1050)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.map(WordCount.java:92)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.map(WordCount.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.run(WordCount.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

14/05/10 19:11:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1399731445858_0009_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1050)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.map(WordCount.java:92)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.map(WordCount.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at WordCount$MyMapper.run(WordCount.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

14/05/10 19:11:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/05/10 19:11:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1399731445858_0009 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1399731445858_0009_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

14/05/10 19:11:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 6
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=4
        Launched map tasks=4
        Other local map tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=22040
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line 
`public static class MyMapper extends Mapper LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>`, you are telling that output key will be of type Text and output value will be of type IntWritable.
Whereas, in you map function 
`protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)` 
in this line, you are writing out LongWritable key and Text value. `super.map(key, value, context);`.
In super.map there will be a type conversion like (Text) key and (Intwritable) value and here the error generates.
change one or the other.

Comment: Thank you! I solve my problem thanks your answer. I would have voted up your post if I had 15 reputation.

Comment: you could accept the solution then..For help look here - "http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow"